# Full-text search in binaries in Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, full-text-search

My current project is to create file storage system, that will contain office files(.doc, .ppt), .pdf and images. I need to have full-text search on text through files, different user groups, storing and retrieving files from\to some users.

Is MongoDB is good way to do this?

Has it full-text search through binaries(or office documents are stored in other way in Mongo?)?

How full-text search works with GridFS?

Could I store metadata(text and information about file) from pdf and office files and images on gridFS?

Will ElasticSearch be a good approach, if there were not really big amount of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Search is the better choice as it is a search engine and MongoDB is a database.

You need to install the [The Ingest Attachment Processor Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html). This provides you support to index your document files into Elastic Search.

MongoDB supports full text search on text but not binary data by an index https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/ but the tokenizer cannot be configured in so many details as you can do it for a search engine.

Having not so many documents/data is never a problem. But you should still choose the right technology for your needs. And what you need is a file analyzer to parse the documents and a searchable index to provide the results. MongoDB is missing the first part and Elastic Search is offering you both highly integrated.

Elastic Search can also store your complete document to be served as result for a search. So you do not need a database (e.g. MongoDB or MySQL) for your solution. But depending on the number of results for a search and the size of your documents the answer to a search can be slower in this approach, as it is possible that multiple huge documents need to be served as result for a search query.

In a general solution the Search Engine would give you a document ID and some meta information (title, author, last update, etc.) about the document as result and not the full document. In this way you have to transport less data and the response is faster. The user can choose depending on the meta data which document to display, if there are multiple results for the search. The document to be desplayed gets loaded by another request with the document ID. e.g. from a database or file system.

Comment: So you suggest storing actual files in MongoDB, but use Elastic to search through data? Does Elastic itself store data or it only read it from database?


Why full-text search isn't good in Mongo? Or it doesn't work well with words search in files?

Comment: Sorry for a lot of questions :)

Comment: @Xerocry: I updated my answer. I hope this answers your question.